# Install Fabric8 on openshift docker instance

Tags: docker, openshift-origin, fabric8

I try to get started with fabric 8 and open shift on docker. An open shift instance (single docker container) is running as described here: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#running-in-a-docker-container. I installed fabric 8 as http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/openshift.html and now the basic pods are running.

But I cannot reach the service

```
oc get services
NAME              CLUSTER_IP       EXTERNAL_IP   PORT(S)                 SELECTOR                                                 AGE
docker-registry   172.30.194.44    <none>        5000/TCP                docker-registry=default                                  18h
fabric8           172.30.178.196                 80/TCP                  group=io.fabric8.apps,project=console,provider=fabric8   18h
kubernetes        172.30.0.1       <none>        443/TCP,53/UDP,53/TCP   <none>                                                   20h
router            172.30.77.252    <none>        80/TCP                  router=router                                            18h
oc describe service fabric8
Name:           fabric8
Namespace:      default
Labels:         group=io.fabric8.apps,project=console,provider=fabric8,version=2.2.116
Selector:       group=io.fabric8.apps,project=console,provider=fabric8
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         172.30.178.196
Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   30308/TCP
Endpoints:      172.17.0.2:9090
Session Affinity:   None
No events.

ping 172.17.0.2:9090
ping: unknown host 172.17.0.2:9090
gheiler@testCluster:~$ ping 172.30.178.196
PING 172.30.178.196 (172.30.178.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 62.218.18.245 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 62.218.18.245 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

In the troubleshooting section of: http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/openshift.html 
some ideas like

```
corsAllowedOrigins:
  - .*
```

are suggested. But I do not know how to enable them in the docker container. Do you have any ideas why I cannot reach my basic fabric8 console?

Comment: try to ping/curl port 80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to access a service on OpenShift remotely then you need to ensure you've deployed a router & added a `Route`. You can read more on routing in OpenShift at https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html.

In this case if you add a route with:

`cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: fabric8-console
pec:
  host: <EXTERNALLY_RESOLVE_DNS>
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: fabric8
EOF`

As some extra info, you cannot target `ping` at a port. Ping uses a different network protocol, ICMP, which doesn't have the notion of ports. Also, both services & pods don't respond to ping so you will not be able to ping them. If you're trying to check connectivity then you can use the `nc` utility:

```
nc -v  <address> <port>
```

This will report connection success if the address/port is reachable. Note that in OpenShift, pod IPs & service IPs are generally only routeable inside the cluster, i.e. on nodes, so trying this from outside the cluster will probably fail.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I have a different problem http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105350/fabric8 please may I ask you a couple of questions here.

Comment: Sorry not enough karma - I feel this should be the accepted answer, not the other one. You can come talk to the fabric8 team on IRC at freenode.net #fabric8

Comment: Fixed changed to better solution

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a route to reach the fabric8 pod in openshift ?

```
oc get route
```